# Google maps: polyline from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, loops

I have an array, full of coordinates and entries. The thing is, I want to get a polyline which connects all the point coordinates in the array.
Placing markers and infowindows are fine but I can't get the polyline.

I need to go through the array by a loop because I want to use the same way for other coordinates again.

Here is the code:

```
var places = [
['New Delhi', 28.6139587,77.208684],
['Amritsar', 31.643628, 74.859624],
['Srinagar', 34.09, 74.79],
['Kargil', 34.55, 76.133333],
['Alchi', 34.2334, 77.1625],
['Leh', 34.145397, 77.567614]
];

for (c = 0; c < places.length; c++){
    var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(places[c][1], places[c][2])
    poly.push(coords);
}

console.log(poly);

var Itinerary = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: poly,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#ffd500',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 5
});

Itinerary.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a javascript error in your posted code: `Uncaught ReferenceError: poly is not defined`.

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/x64nvegy/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var poly = []; // added this

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

  var places = [
    ['New Delhi', 28.6139587, 77.208684],
    ['Amritsar', 31.643628, 74.859624],
    ['Srinagar', 34.09, 74.79],
    ['Kargil', 34.55, 76.133333],
    ['Alchi', 34.2334, 77.1625],
    ['Leh', 34.145397, 77.567614]
  ];

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (c = 0; c < places.length; c++) {
    var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(places[c][1], places[c][2])
    poly.push(coords);
    bounds.extend(coords);
  }

  console.log(poly);

  var Itinerary = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: poly,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#ffd500',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 5
  });

  Itinerary.setMap(map);
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```